# Publish option disabled in win Vista after converting a website to web application

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2005, windows-vista, publish

I have converted a web site to a webapplication. In windows Vista, the option of publish is no more available. Any idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Also If mixed platformis selected it published well. But I want to use x86 for compilation and publish on a 64 machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't publish from a Web Application, regardless of your operating system.

What you need todo is add a Web Setup project to the solution.  Right click on the Web Setup project in solution explorer, click Add > Project Output and add the Primary Output and Content Files from your Web Application project.

Comment: Please elaborate the steps. As I can do a publish on Windows XP